# Asp net, stream raw h264 to browser

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, video-streaming, h.264

I looking for read raw h264 streaming video into a web browser.
It is a live flow (so there is no way to convert file), from a raspberry's camera.

I successfully read this flow with vlc with a manipulation (forcing the codec input : https://www.unifore.net/ip-video-surveillance/how-to-play-264-video-files-from-ip-cameras-dvrs.html ).
But h264 raw without a container (like mp4) seems prohibited by browsers.

There no many ressources about this point. And some questions on Stackoverflow.com like this post are asked without answer.

Maybe I do not use the good way, so all suggestions are welcome. :)

Thanks !

Comment: You are correct, browsers will not play a 264 bitstream. It must be in a container. The only possible solution, it’s write the stream to a container before writing it to the MAE source buffer.

Comment: I think it's the best solution. But I do not know how to do that, and the examples I seen on the web, works with files using ffmpeg, no stream.

Comment: Is it an RTP (or even RTSP) link? Does the video tag of your browser not accept RTP link? _Eg:_ `<video src="rtp://domain.com/stream"> </video>`.

Comment: rtp seems accepted by most of browsers. So I looking for something like that. I using vlc for transcoding the stream to mp4 and readable for browsers, without success for now.

Comment: It took time but I found an another way.
I did not succeed with bitstream with .net framework.

So I created a ffmpeg server :
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=43&t=223934&p=1374216

It's ok now.
Thanks anyway ! :)